# drop ip blacklist with firewalld centos 7

Tags: linux, iptables, centos7, firewalld

## Question 1

I have I very long list 1500+ ips in a file lets say /etc/blocklist.ips each ip in a line of the file. How can I DROP  for every ip in the file with firewalld from centos 7 ? also I been looking there are .xml files in /firewald folder so this mean that I should create my blocklist in a .xml file?

## Question 2

beeing Firewalld stopped doens't mean rules created with firewalld are not working on iptables right?

## Question 3

Flushing iptables will also delete everything on firewalld?

Comment: Thank you for posting on ServerFault. Getting good answers requires the effort of [writing a good question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) and as it stands now yours is three, albeit somewhat related, questions in one, making it slightly difficult to provide you with a quality answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to manage firewall rules with large numbers of IP-addresses remains with [**`ipset`**](http://ipset.netfilter.org/).

Then create a set of ip-addresses:

```
ipset create blacklist hash:ip hashsize 4096
```

and add each of the ip-addresses you need to block:

```
ipset add blacklist 192.168.0.5 
ipset add blacklist 192.168.0.100 
ipset add blacklist 192.168.0.220
```

AFAIK firewalld does not yet have a API method for adding the required iptables rule that works on the match module so you're going to end up doing something slightly ugly like this, I think:

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0  -m set --match-set blacklist src -j DROP
```

instead of the usual `iptables -I INPUT  -m set --match-set blacklist src -j DROP` you would have done without firewalld.