# firewalld, `--add-rich-rule` and missing blacklist set

Tags: centos, firewall, centos7, firewalld, ipset

My server uses Centos8 quite recently installed (~1 year).

After trying to ban an IP:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=extz --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="49.88.112.70" drop'
```

My system seams to be corrupt:

```
# firewall-cmd --reload
Error: COMMAND_FAILED: Direct: '/usr/sbin/iptables-restore -w -n' failed: iptables-restore v1.4.21: Set blacklist doesn't exist.

Error occurred at line: 2
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
```

But the restart of the service works without error messages:

```
# systemctl restart firewalld
```

If would like (besides to understand what happened)

1. Either to restore the old situation (a `--remove-rich-rule` does not seam to be enough)
2. or make the banning method work (somehow add a set with ipset?)

Comment: Are you sure this is CentOS 8? This distribution does not use `iptables`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I installed it last year and I could have bet any amount of money, but you are right: `CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)`

Comment: @A.B, yes, `CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)`

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Using+ipset+to+block+IP+addresses+-+firewall) we create the `blacklist` set:

```
# sudo yum install ipset # was already installed
# sudo ipset create blacklist hash:ip hashsize 4096
# firewall-cmd --reload
success
```

As pointed out by @MichaelHampto in the comments, the error arrises probably from a previous (partial) attempt to reach the same goal (to block IPs); something like the the following:
[drop ip blacklist with firewalld centos 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/674106/drop-ip-blacklist-with-firewalld-centos-7)

The solution of the error should be correct but is not related with the rich rules.

Comment: Hmm. The rich rule you referred to doesn't create or reference an ipset `blacklist` (or any ipset). Likely the problem is elsewhere, and only showed up when you reloaded firewalld.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I probably tried something else before using the rich rules to reach the same goal. I edit the answer.